# OAuth2 protected Spring Boot REST Api with local user database and authentication

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I'm looking to build a Spring Boot REST API for an Android application.
Some of user specific resources should be protected by OAuth2.

My problem is - I don't wan't to use the social logins for my user authentication. I wan't to have my own user database (SQL) with my own user registration, that allows the user to login using username/password.

I'm new to the Spring Boot world - but have been looking on quite a few examples online, and I can see that Spring has a lot of useful libraries for user handling and OAuth.

But I can't seem to find some good examples that describes the proces of creating an  Authentication Server that uses a local user database, and at the same time has an open user registration API.

So my question is - does any of You guys/girls have some links to guides that does this?

Thanks

Comment: May I ask why you want to utilize OAuth which seems inappropriate and overkill for the scenario you describe?

Comment: Yep the OAuth approach is quite cumbersome - but the thought was to keep state away from the server. I can always fallback to the old sessionId approach but this also has quite a few drawbacks.

If you have some other suggestions I'm open for other ideas.

Comment: Your described scenario calls for server side sessions or client tokens (e.g. JWT) - But perhaps I'm just missing the big picture.You need three parties to make reasonable use of OAuth. With your Spring Boot App and the Android app, I just count two. Which is the 3rd one?

Answer (score 3):

Hope these will help:

- https://blog.varonis.com/introduction-to-oauth/
- http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angularjs

Also You can go with JWT Auth tokens:

- https://github.com/cpapidas/Spring-Boot-OAuth2-JWT-MySQL
- http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt

For more samples on Spring boot, You can refer following:

- https://github.com/spring-guides

Best of luck.